# onclick div hide, setTimeout div hide

Tags: jquery, css

i am trying to do something. if click one **add** `#add-conferance` then menu will show `.add-contact`. when click **hide** then it show hide. also i make setTimeout 7sec but i want to this setTimeout will fired when my mouse on outside `.add-contact` it is meaning when mouse not on that menu then after few sec later menu will hide.

```
 $('#add-conferance').click(function () {
            $('.add-contact').animate({right: "0%"}, 600, 'swing');
      window.setTimeout(function(){$(".add-contact").animate({right: "-60%"}, 900, 'swing');}, 7000);
        return false;
 });

  $('#hide-conferance').click(function () {
            $('.add-contact').animate({right: "-60%"}, 600, 'swing');

        return false;
 });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/2w3ywvu4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [`mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event to `.add-contact` then:

```
 $('#add-conferance').click(function () {
     $('.add-contact').animate({right: "0%"}, 600, 'swing');
     return false;
 });

  $('#hide-conferance').click(function () {
     $('.add-contact').animate({right: "-60%"}, 600, 'swing');
     return false;
 });

 $('.add-contact').mouseleave( function() {
     window.setTimeout(function(){$(".add-contact").animate({right: "-60%"}, 900, 'swing');}, 7000);
 });
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2w3ywvu4/2/)

And if you want it to not hide if user moves mouse outside block and then point it there again before 7000ms pass you need to add timeout handler and use [`mouseenter`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event:

```
 var hideHandler;
 $('.add-contact').mouseleave( function() {
     hideHandler = window.setTimeout(function(){$(".add-contact").animate({right: "-60%"}, 900, 'swing');}, 7000);
 });
 $('.add-contact').mouseenter( function() {
   window.clearTimeout(hideHandler);
 });
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2w3ywvu4/5/)

Comment: Thank you so much. updated one here https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/2w3ywvu4/3/ but there have one issue. say like i keep move mouse on menu section then mouse point go outside i keep outside 2 sec then again mouse move to inside menu. in this scenario menu not stay. i think because of when mouse was outside settimeout fired so it is not reset again then mouse come back again.

Comment: @pagol see my updated answer, and this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2w3ywvu4/5/ Does it solve your problem?